# Can we create Ignite In memory Table with purging

Tags: ignite, in-memory-database

I am a new bee to Ignite.

Can we create or configure In Memory Ignite Table with purging time,

My Ask is -> A record inserted at X point of time shall automatically be deleted after 3 Hrs

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at expiry policies documentation: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/expiry-policies

`CreatedExpiryPolicy` should solve your problem.